# case of not returning exact list. erlang

Tags: erlang

```
HeirListFormatted = [{code, 1}, ...],
HeirCode = proplists:get_value(code, HeirListFormatted),
HeirList = [<<"1">>, <<"2">>, ...],
HeirListCodes = [case to_integer(X) of HeirCode -> []; _-> form_data:to_integer(X) end || X <- HeirList].
```

Here `HeirListCodes` is returning a list like this: `[[],2, 3,[],...]`. But I want the code in one line and `HeirListCodes` should return me a list like `[2,3, ...]`.

Thank you inadvance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it what you are looking for?

```
[Y || X <- HeirList , Y <- [binary_to_integer(X)],Y =/= HeirCode].
```

**[Edit]**

if `HeirCode == undefined`:

Without any change, the filter condition will be always true, and you will get the list of binaries transformed onto a list of integer.

If you add the filter condition `HeirCode =/= undefined` this filter will be always false, so the result will be an empty list.

So the solution really depend on the result you expect.

Comment: Further to this question can we do like this ?

`[Y || X <- HeirList , Y <- [binary_to_integer(X)], **HeirCode =/= undefined** andalso Y =/= HeirCode ]`

But seems to be not working.

Comment: what is the result you expect if HeirCode is undefined?

Comment: Yes, Sometimes HeirCode could be undefined.